# How to make customized admin template work with grappelli?

Tags: django, django-grappelli

I am sing grappelli, the admin pages look good, but now I need modify some pages, for example, I created templates/admin/index.html under  my app, it works, but grappelli doesn't apply the style on this customized template, any idea how I can make it work as the default admin templates?

Answer (score 0):

figured out, I need customize on the grappelli template files not the default admin template files